# Prefix Expression Evaluation(Using Stacks)-Java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, expression, prefix

I have a question about my method that is supposed to evaluate prefix expressions. I have gotten it to work for post fix expressions using stacks so I figured that it should be similar. I need to read from right to left rather than left to right. Here is my method for evaluating, any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated:

```
// evaluates a preFix expression
public static int evaluate(String input)
{
    int number, leftOperand, rightOperand, result;
    char operator;
    String token;

    // create an integer stack
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    // create string tokenizer containing string input
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);

    // while input string has more tokens
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        token = tokenizer.nextToken();// get next token
        // if token is character
        if (isChar(token)) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(token);// push into stack
            stack.push(number);
        // if token is operator
        } else {
            operator = token.charAt(0);// get operator
            rightOperand = stack.pop();// pop two numbers
            leftOperand = stack.pop();
            result = evaluate(rightOperand, leftOperand, operator);// evaluate
            stack.push(result);// push result
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();// final answer
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:572)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at PrefixEvaluator.evaluate(PrefixEvaluator.java:40)
at PrefixEvaluator.main(PrefixEvaluator.java:99)
```

Comment: well ... have you tried your idea (reading backwards)? did it work?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it gave me an error.

Comment: And if anyone wants to see my full code to elaborate just ask, I want to be clear as possible.

Comment: I can't really see how this would work for any type of expression that has an operand following the operator. When the token is an operator it is popping values from the stack that haven't been put there yet.

Comment: 'Gave me an error' is not a problem description. Try again.

Comment: @sprinter Not if you feed it a prefix expression right to left (or postfix left to right).

Comment: @EJP , Sorry this is the error that I am receiving:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:572)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at PrefixEvaluator.evaluate(PrefixEvaluator.java:40)
 at PrefixEvaluator.main(PrefixEvaluator.java:99)

Comment: @EJP I should have been more explicit - I can't see how this would work for infix operators.

Comment: @sprinter for this specific program it's only going to be fed prefix operations using stack. I have already written a program that successfully accepts postfix expressions. Just need to figure out the prefix only.

Comment: @sprinter it isn't *meant* to work for infix operators. Do read the question. Even the title.

Comment: @kbelt721 That should have been edited into your question. Illegibile where it is.

Answer (score 0):

The`NumberFormatException` says that you tried to parse '-' as a number. So there must be something wrong with the code you  didn't post that decides whether a token is a number or an operator.